# SDL2 Object Oriented Wrapper; 1000+ Virtual Function calls a frame; Is there any way to optimize this?

Tags: c++, function, oop, polymorphism, sdl-2

I'm writing an object oriented wrapper for SDL2. I have decided to make 2 classes: a Sprite class, and a Rectangle Class. I used a bit of polymorphism so I don't have to overload the `draw` function for every drawable object. I have a base class `Drawable` which has a pure virutal function `draw`.

Now `Sprite` and `Rect` inherit `Drawable` and define the `draw` function to suit the style of class. Now, when I have to draw many things to the screen, I'm taking a pointer to `Drawable`, then calling the `draw` method. This is happening 1000+ times a second.

If I look at my CPU usage, it's about 10%. I know 1000+ Sprites being drawn every 60 times a second is going to hinder my CPU usage, but I didn't think it would this much.

Now, my question: Is there any way to optimize this? Maybe take out the pure virtual function and just overload the functions?

My Code (I tried to shorten it as much as possible):

**Sprite::Draw Declaration**

```
void Draw() override;
```

**Sprite::Draw Function**

```
void Sprite::Draw() {

    // rect is SDL_Rect

    rect.x = rect.x - window->getCamera().getCoords().x;
    rect.y = rect.y - window->getCamera().getCoords().y;
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(window->renderer, texture, NULL, &rect, 0, NULL, flip);

}
```

**The Function that calls Sprite::Draw**

```
void Window::Draw(Drawable *d) {

    d->Draw();

}
```

**Drawing Loop**

```
// 1024 grass Sprites

for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {

            mainWindow.Draw(&grass[i]); // Calls Window::Draw

}
```

As I said earlier, it is eating up about 10% of my CPU usage. I have an AMD 6300, and a NVIDIA GTX 750Ti. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013.

The executable name is OBA.exe

[image: OBA]

Comment: What about templates?

Comment: @Satus I'll try that. If it doesn't work then I'll put that I tried templates in the question.

Comment: Are you sure that this hight CPU usage is cause by virtual functions, and not by actual drawing? Did you profile? Because drawing something on a screen take so long time, that virtual function call time becomes insignificant.

Comment: Stupid but neccessary question. Your build is optimized, right?

Comment: @Satus No, templates did not work. I've even tried defining a function specifically for the `Sprite` class, and no performance changes.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, I am using /02

Comment: @Satus I just profiled it, and it isn't Sprite::Draw or SDL_RenderCopyEx. It's actually SDL_LogCritical. I'm researching it right now.

Comment: @GregM I am not familiar with SDL itself, but I can say for sure that calling  virtual functions 1024 will not create any noticeable performance downgrade. But if you aim for your wrapper to be used in high-loaded applications, than you should try to eliminate any possible overhead. And templates are a good substitution for polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the textures for these grass sprites be condensed into 1 texturemap and then you draw a portion of it (the third param, srcrect -- https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopyEx)?

I'm guessing you don't have 1024 unique grass textures, but a handful of repeated ones. Combine them all into one image and load that as a grass texture. 
Your sprite class then needs to just define a `SDL_Rect` for which part of the texture it uses to draw.

Sample texture:

[image: <img>http://i.imgur.com/MY0BIh2.png</img>]

Say your sprite uses texture 0, it's `srcrect` would be 0,0,32,32. Drawing it just adds one parameter to your RenderCopy call.

```
SDL_RenderCopyEx(window->renderer, texture, &srcrect, &rect, 0, NULL, flip);
```

This should improve performance for drawing a lot of sprites. Additionally, you could only draw sprites if they are in the camera view.

Comment: I am only using one grass texture, which the Sprite class has a SDL_Texture pointer to. I think I might only draw the sprites in the current view too.

Comment: If they are all the same, why do you need 1024 of them? Couldn't you just have 1 and draw it in 1024 places? Additionally, if it is some sort of background, could you draw all of that onto a texture once and then just reuse that texture?

Comment: I don't need 1024 SDL_Textures, what I did was make a `Texture` class, that contains the grass texture, then in the `Sprite` class I had a pointer to this texture. Doesn't really matter now, because I'm just drawing what is in the `Camera`'s view, and the usage is down to about 0.1%!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, what I did was just draw the Sprites that were currently in the Camera's view. The reason SDL_LogCritical was being called so much is being every SDL_RenderCopyEx call, SDL_LogCritical is called, along with other SDL functions. But by drawing just what the user can see, I got the CPU usage down to about 0.1%